# unable to access video files from external storage directory with file provider in API version 23 and upper. Code is given below

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

I want to play video in Video view, I have tried so many solutions but I am not able to access image file and video file as well.
It allows me to access image files when I run application for second time.
[Click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJtT.png),
[Full Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7TaC.png)

I already have run time permissions, but system won't allow me to access images and files.

Here is my code -

**MainActivity**
`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    String image = "/ImageVideos/1501064538061.jpg";
    String video = "/ImageVideos/20170707155916_mmy037p0xZzcW.mp4";

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    String strFileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    String strImgDir = strFileDir + image;
    String strVideoDir = strFileDir + video;

    File fileImg = new File(strImgDir);
    File fileVideo = new File(strVideoDir);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

        if (!checkPermission()) {
            requestPermission();
        }           

        Uri imgContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileImg);

        Uri videoContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileVideo);


        this.grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), imgContentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        this.grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), videoContentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        imageView.setImageURI(imgContentUri);

        videoView.setVideoPath(String.valueOf(videoContentUri));
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_ALL);
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ALL:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean WriteExternalAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean ReadExternalAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (ReadExternalAccepted && WriteExternalAccepted) {
                    //Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Denied, You cannot access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                        PERMISSION_ALL);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

`
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<provider 
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
   android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
   android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<path xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <root-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</path>
```

Comment: your need to ask for run time permission [read about this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Here i have changed folder name from RecurPostVideos to ImageVideos.

Comment: I already gave run time permissions. @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: share code for that permission

Comment: edited code, please check it

Answer (score 0):

try this

**step 1 :- add this permission in manifest file**

```
 android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
```

**step 2 : ask runtime permission**

```
 String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                {permission}, 1010);

    }
```

**step 3: handle permsiion result**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1010) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_not_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3828119 but your error show that permission denide

Comment: Added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>, but not working

Comment: try one this give permission manually from setting than run your code

Comment: Giving me following Error: E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648,   Can't play video

Comment: Check it, Click on Full Error Log

Comment: it is FileNotFound exeception my friend

Comment: Yes, I know, but file is already there, file uri problem is there?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: setting->installedapp->yourapp->app permissions like than enable permssion and run again

Comment: There are 2 permissions only, Contacts and Storage, Storage is enabled already.